# Determining irreducible elements and finding ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

My question arises from considering the following rings:

- The subring $R_1$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ with elements $\{a/b : b \space \text{odd}\}$
- The subring $R_2$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ given by $R_2 = \{\frac{a}{2^{k}3^{l}} | a \in \mathbb{Z}, k, l \in \mathbb{Z_{\ge 0}}\}$
- The subring $R_3$ of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ of rational functions $P(x)/Q(x)$ such that $Q(0) \neq 0$ and $Q(1) \neq 1$

In all three cases it is fairly straightforward to find the group of units. I struggle however finding the irreducible elements and finding maximal and principle ideals in the given rings. Is there a general strategy to tackle such problems? What are things that I need to look out for/consider when dealing with such problems?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think $R_3$ is a subring of $\Bbb Q(x)$. For instance, $\frac{x+1}{x+2},\, \frac{x+2}{x+1}\in R_3$, but their product isn't.

Comment: I do not see how this product is not in $R_3$.

Comment: Because it is $1=\frac11$, obviously.

Comment: But you can choose $P$ and $Q$ such that the quotient is identically 1, but $Q(1) \neq 1$ right?

Comment: Just like you can for all $P$ and $Q$ that do not satisfy the second condition: if it goes bad, pick $\frac{2P(x)}{2Q(x)}$, or $\frac{(x+1)P(x)}{(x+1)Q(x)}$ if you want something to stay monic.